# How can I use get_option to exlude a category from loop in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a code like this in my index ,archives etc..

```
<?php
$page_num = $paged;
if ($pagenum='') $pagenum =1;
query_posts('showposts=16&paged='.$page_num); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
```

My Option

get_cat_id(get_option('mtn_blogcategory')

But I have a custom blog template and I want to display blog posts only on blog template how can I exlude category using this option above from a loop like index,archive,search etc..? 
Thanks

---

thanks for your response I tried like this

```
<?php
$bcat = get_option('mtn_blogcat');
$page_num = $paged;
if ($pagenum='') $pagenum =1;
query_posts('showposts=16&paged='.$page_num.'&cat=-'.$bcat); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
```

Did'nt work :(

Comment: get the `ID` from the options table then save it in a variable then exclude the category like this `query_posts('showposts=16&paged='.$page_num.'&cat=-'.$var);` according to [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Exclude_Categories_From_Your_Home_Page)

Comment: The code wich I gave is from index.php and archive.php not from blog template thanks for your help but where to add that in template-blog.php?

Comment: get_option('mtn_blogcategory') is my blog category wich I want to exlude from other loops that code didnt work

Comment: where ever you want to exclude any category using `query_posts` just use `query_posts('cat=-45')` this code will exclude the category having `id=45` from the loop

Comment: not working this I want to exlude using $variable without using the id

Answer (score 0):

**A few things first:**

The function `query_posts()` is used to alter the main query. It isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. So unless you have a very good reason not to, use `WP_Query` instead:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

It seems as if you're trying to create a query that gets all posts **except** those that are in the category with *slug* `mtn_blogcat`. You're also trying to make sure it's on the correct page and that it shows 16 posts per page.

The parameters needed to achieve this are `cat`, `paged` and `posts_per_page`.

Assuming you don't already know the ID of the category you wish to exclude, you first need to get it. You can get the ID either by the category's *slug* or by its *name*.

**If you know the category's name:**

```
$cat_ID = get_cat_ID( 'Category Name' );
```

**If you know the category's slug:**

```
$category = get_category_by_slug( 'category-slug' ); 
$cat_ID = $category->term_id;
```

You should only need to use one of those function. It seems the slug might be `mtn_blogcat`(?), if that's the case use `get_category_by_slug( 'mtn_blogcat' );`

Next, we're getting the current page number:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
```

And lastly we set the `posts_per_page` to 16:

```
$posts_per_page = 16;
```

**Putting it together:**

```
<?php
// Assuming you know the category slug
$category = get_category_by_slug( 'category-slug' ); 
$cat_ID = $category->term_id;
$exclude_cat = '-' . $cat_ID;

$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1; 

$posts_per_page = 16;

$args = array(
    'cat' => $exclude_cat,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

        <!-- Put posts markup here -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The only thing left is to put the existing post markup where I've put the comment:

```
<!-- Put posts markup here -->
```

Comment: Thankyou  but can I use $variable instead the name of category    $bcat = get_option('mtn_blogcat');

Comment: thankyou verymuch for your helps maybe I am wrong but didnt work I just tested cannot hide that category's posts from index with that code I0m making this with a plugin but I dont want to use plugins in my theme I'm very happy because you want to help me guys and would be the correct code that wich you gave but on my theme I cant get to work.